# How to determine if there are no errors anymore in Validation.ErrorEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, events

I've very simple check if there are validation error somewhere in my window (assuming what all bindings will have `NotifyOnValidationError` set):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new VM();
    AddHandler(Validation.ErrorEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
        var args = (ValidationErrorEventArgs)e;
        var binding = (BindingExpression)args.Error.BindingInError;
        Title = binding.HasError ? $"Error {args.Error.ErrorContent}" : "";
    }), true);
}
```

The event is rised when errors appear/disappear, but for some reasons `HasError` still `true` when there are no more errors and `ErrorContent` contains old error text.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Below is a simple MCVE with validation that `Test` should be `0`.

Binding errors (entering `0a` or empty string) are set/reset correctly. Validation error is set correctly (when entering `1`), but is not reset (when entering `0`). Why?

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChange` makes no difference.

[image]

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

View Model:

```
public class VM : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    int _test;
    public int Test
    {
        get => _test;
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            _error = value == 0 ? null : "Must be 0";
            ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(nameof(Test)));
        }
    }

    string _error;
    public bool HasErrors => _error != null;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_error != null)
            yield return _error;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to read and act upon [ValidationErrorEventArgs.Action Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationerroreventargs.action?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_ValidationErrorEventArgs_Action) ?

Comment: @Fildor, it looks like it, thanks. You could as well make it an answer. My approach was simply wrong ([msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.error) could have a simple example), I was thinking that it's my job to determine if errors have to be added or removed.

Comment: I think the crux is this: _"Also note that a valid value transfer in either direction (target-to-source or source-to-target) clears the Validation.Errorsattached property."_ So, by the time `binding.HasError` is checked in the handler in your example, it has not been cleared yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `Title` from within the handler, I think you need to consider the 
[ValidationErrorEventArgs.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationerroreventargs.action?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_ValidationErrorEventArgs_Action) Property:

> Gets a value that indicates whether the error is a new error or an existing error that has now been cleared.

I am not 100% sure, but I suspect that by the time you check the `HasError` Property, it has not yet been cleared. (Suspicion based on *"Also note that a valid value transfer in either direction (target-to-source or source-to-target) clears the Validation.Errorsattached property."* from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.error?view=netframework-4.8))

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to maintain list of errors, adding them when `args.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added` and removing on `Removed` and only when list is empty there are no more errors.